# How to create equilateral(regular) triangles inside a region to get a 2d mesh?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, graphics, cgal

In my program, I want to implement the following features:

1. Users draw a closed curve using mouse, and this curve is actually a set of point
2. Given a closed curve drawn by users, this program would create equilateral triangles inside this curve to get a 2d mesh.

Just like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmdFH.png), the first one is the closed curve drawn by user. Then I want to create equilateral triangles inside this curve(the second one), and move those points which are not in these created triangles's vertex to get a 2d mesh(the third one).

I've looked up CGAL which has a lot of mesh generation algorithm, but I can't find a way to do what I need. So does anyone know how I could achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your curve is closed then you can use the [2D meshing package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html). A simple example is [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#title11).
Here is an example I generated using CGAL embedded into the [Ipe](http://ipe.otfried.org/) software.

[image]

Comment: I tried this the example you gave, But  I met two problem, one is I can't get as regular as yours, it also have some [irregular triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RADFf.png), and the other problem is I get some unexpected triangle result, such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeXZV.png). Could you show me how you get you result using cgal?

Comment: My guess is that your are also displaying triangles that are outside of the domain. Try uising the function [`is_in_domain()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classDelaunayMeshFaceBase__2.html#a42249ae38c23bf5b6aaf64db9975316c) to filter those faces. Then if not regular enough you can still try to smooth the mesh. See [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_2mesh_optimization_8cpp-example.html) example.